# Getting the index from a hyperlink inside of a listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

So I have a listbox that is being populated by an array and has 25 entries in it. In each row the listbox has, I have a "comments" hyperlink button that has separate functionality than what the listbox does. So, since I'm not technically selecting the listbox item, it doesn't return an index. Anyways, here's the code:

```
<ListBox Name="mainListBox" SelectionChanged="mainListBox_SelectionChanged" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Source="{Binding data.thumbnail}" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TitleInfo" Text="{Binding data.title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" Width="370" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorInfo" Text="{Binding data.author}" FontSize="15" Margin="2" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Score:" Margin="2" FontSize="14"  />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="score" Text="{Binding data.score}" FontSize="14" Margin="2"/>
                                <HyperlinkButton Content="Comments" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" FontSize="15" x:Name="commentsLink" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I want this line:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Comments" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" FontSize="15" x:Name="commentsLink" />
```

to give me the index in the code behind the xaml file.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

edit:
Here's the code that is being problematic.

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hb = sender as HyperlinkButton;
        if (hb != null)
        {
            var obj = hb.Tag as RootObject;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(obj.data.children[0].data.title, obj.data.children[0].data.author,  MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
        textBlock1.Text = Global.sUrl;
    }
```

Also, here is the code for my object:

```
public class MediaEmbed
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public int? width { get; set; }
    public bool? scrolling { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }
}
public class Oembed
{
    public string provider_url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string author_name { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public int thumbnail_width { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string provider_name { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int thumbnail_height { get; set; }
    public string author_url { get; set; }
}
public class Media
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Oembed oembed { get; set; }
}
public class Data2
{
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public MediaEmbed media_embed { get; set; }
    public object levenshtein { get; set; }
    public string subreddit { get; set; }
    public string selftext_html { get; set; }
    public string selftext { get; set; }
    public object likes { get; set; }
    public bool saved { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool clicked { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Media media { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public bool over_18 { get; set; }
    public bool hidden { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string subreddit_id { get; set; }
    public string author_flair_css_class { get; set; }
    public int downs { get; set; }
    public bool is_self { get; set; }
    public string permalink { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double created { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string author_flair_text { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public double created_utc { get; set; }
    public int num_comments { get; set; }
    public int ups { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public Data2 data { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public string modhash { get; set; }
    public Child[] children { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
    public object before { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

RootObject contains data, which leads to child(an array), which leads to data2 which has all the information I want. Thanks a lot for your help up to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` parameter. Note that the `{Binding}` binds the entire object itself.

For example,

```
class Myobj
{
   string param1 { get; set; } 
   string param2 { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<Myobj> collection;
```

If collection is your ItemsSource, then inside your DataTemplate , a {Binding} refers to an entire instance of Myobj.

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Comments" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" FontSize="15" x:Name="commentsLink" Tag="{Binding}" />
```

then in your Click Event, simply cast sender to a hyperlink button, and get the Tag.

```
...
var hb = sender as HyperLinkButton;
if (hb != null)
  {
     var obj = hb.Tag as Myobj;
     if (obj != null)
     { 

     }
  }
...
```

Check out this cheatsheet on binding. It's very helpful.

http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Note that this implementation does not use `SelectedIndex` - but it doesn't need to. Since the `HyperLinkButton` has a reference to the object that you are generating the `ListBoxItem` for, there's no need for it.

Finally, here's a sample project

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ef08824b672fb5d8&resid=EF08824B672FB5D8!352&parid=EF08824B672FB5D8!343

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. First off, I am not using an observable collection but instead I am using an array. I am parsing data pulled from a website so I just went with what they provided. Basically, the listbox runs through a an array of objects that contains several strings and bools etc, and I am pulling the data from an index of one of those objects. The line to take the data is this: data.children[0].data.title; or url, author etc.

Comment: @Wilcoholic did you try the above solution? It should work with an array.

Comment: Yes I tried the above solution and it didn't resolve the problem. I replaced the MyObj part in your code snippet with my object (RootObject) and get an OutofBounds exception in my code. I updated the post to include the click event code. I am not sure I understand what is happening 100% here, so I may have tried to implement this incorrectly.

Comment: @Wilcoholic you're not using the `obj` at all after you cast it - It should be a single item that is in your array.

Comment: @Wilcoholic i.e. No need to use 'selectedIndex' at all. you already have what you want. It's whatever variable contains data.title, data.author, etc.

Comment: Ok, so doing things this way doesn't require mainlistbox.selectedindex..I must admit I still am not sure what you are trying to say. Data.title and Data.author are contained inside of an array in an instance of the my class RootObject..Perhaps an example of what you are trying to explain to me will?

Comment: @Wilcoholic added sample project. Check MainPage.xaml.cs for all the code behind

Comment: Thanks for the sample project. I have adjusted what I had and am still not getting it to execute what is inside of the if (obj != null) statement. Perhaps I should have been more specific with what kind of data structure I am using. It is using the reddit API and came in JSON and was converted to a c# object. It isn't itself an array but contains arrays in it. Ill update the post with the way my code looks now along with the data structure of my object.

Comment: @Wilcoholic try using a standard cast i.e. MyObj obj = (MyObj) sender; instead of using `as`. It will throw exceptions which will help you debug.

Comment: @Wilcoholic in your example, the Tag should be a `Child` object

Comment: Excellent. Just changed the tag from RootObject to Child and it works. Thanks a ton for your help. I had no idea that tag even existed..Thanks again.